# How to disable pull-down menu in android sources?

Tags: android, android-source

I m making aosp android 12 build for single purpose device and i need to disable pull-down menu so users will not be able to turn on/of wifi, bluetooth etc and will not have access to settings.

Does anybody knows how to achieve it? I was looking for it in SystemUI and SystemUI/statusbar sources but I don't even know what I m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In AOSP Android 12 source code go to `packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/StatusBar.java` and find the method `makeStatusBarView()`, Inside the `makeStatusBarView()` method, you can disable the pull-down menu by adding the following line of code

```
// Disable the pull-down menu
mStatusBarWindow.disableExpandStatusBar();
```

This is the file location: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2b6d358d559f31e203f97af0865e67e24c59377b/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/StatusBar.java